# Leaf-based clothing: Practical? Historical? Fictional?

Tags: internal-consistency, history, clothing

Plant-based clothing comes in a variety of forms, both stereotypically and historically: grass skirts, barkcloth, *et cetera*. But one form I have only ever seen in fiction is clothing made from straight-up leaves (whether woven, sown, or whatever). It has a fairly established place in both fantasy garb, and in many stereotypical depictions of tropical attire.

My question is if there's any actual historical precedent for this. Did people ever make clothes out of whole, intact leaves, or was plant fibre the only material ever actually used? How practical would leaf-based clothing, or clothing that incorporated leaves, actually be? In a warm enough climate, with tough enough plants, would it be manageable, or is it all just fiction?

Edit: While hats certainly qualify as a usage of leaves in clothing, I was particularly curious about their potential integration into garments meant to cover the body (such as shirts, skirts, etc.) E.g. Was it ever done? Is it viable? Etc.

Edit #2 (Re-edited, because I'm not the most eloquent fellow): A lot of people have brought up straw and straw hats, and while that's a perfect example of plants being more or less directly integrated into clothing, I'm more curious about the integration of traditional leaves (such as leaves from trees, bushes, etc.). Whether palm fronds qualify as leaves is a question I leave for a more qualified individual than I, but I think, as leaves taken from a larger plant, they work for this question.

Comment: Just to get it off the plate: the common source most of us think of first is the Biblical story of Adam and Eve.  Note, however, that the fig leaves (Genesis 3:7) lasted only as long as the interview with God, who made "coats of skins" to clothe them (Genesis 3:21).  Whether you consider the Biblical story fact or fiction, the fig leaves were used for, what, 30 minutes?

Comment: [Straw hats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_hat) are very popular, aren't they? So that plant fibre(s) are clearly **not** the only material used.

Comment: @AlexP straw **is** plant fibers.

Comment: @RonJohn: [Straw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw) is "an agricultural byproduct consisting of the dry stalks of cereal plants" (and other grasses). I have no idea why you would think that straw is a processed material.

Comment: *"Not merely grass":* so you have something against the Poaceae. What did the Poaceae ever do to you? Please list all plant families whose leaves are not to your liking, so that we can obediently serve your wishes.

Comment: @AlexP why do you think I meant that it was **processed* plant fibers?

Comment: @RonJohn: You said that straw **is** plant fibers. This is plainly wrong. Straw **contains** plant fibers, but then so do leaves and bark. To extract the fibers from straw (or from leaves, or from bark) one must process them. It's like saying that animal skins are collagen.

Comment: @AlexP pulling -- with your bare hands -- strips of fiber from a plant doesn't seem like processing it to me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frond "A frond is a large, divided **leaf**."  And if you don't trust Wikipedia, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frond "a large **leaf** (especially of a palm or fern) usually with many divisions"

Comment: I removed the [tag:magic] tag because, even if it's present in your story, it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Cyn Thanks! I'm not sure how that got there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Taʻovala

> A taʻovala is a [Tongan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonga) dress, a mat wrapped around the waist, worn by men and women, at all formal occasions. The ta'ovala is also commonly seen among the Fijian Lau Islands, a region once heavily influenced by Tongan hegemony and cultural diffusion.
>
> The normal taʻovala, for everyday neat wear, is a short mat, coming halfway up the thighs. It is tied with a rope (*kafa*, often made of coconut coir or of human hair of a deceased ancestor) wrapped around the waist. The mat worn on festive occasions, like a marriage, is much larger and often very nicely decorated. Likewise the taʻovala for a funeral is also a huge mat, but much coarser, not decorated. If the wearer has an inferior rank towards the deceased, the mat is old and torn. The older and more torn it is, the better. All these special mats are kept as precious heirlooms.
>
> Taʻovala are part of the *koloa*, the handicraft goods made by the women. Every woman can do it. If girls do not learn it at home, it will be taught at school. More recently, however, some women specialise in the handicraft and sell their products on the market.
>
> Taʻovala can be made from different materials, natural and introduced:
>
> - Strips of [pandanus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandanus) leaves, usually unpainted, although sometimes black strips are used, and rarely the whole taʻovala is black. The strips range from coarse (15 mm or so as for funerals) to fine (a couple of millimeters, as the *taʻovala loukeha*, in which one is dressed to visit the king). Mats are always woven by hand. Especially the fine mats are therefore very laborious to make, take a long time to complete and are expensive. The oldest and most valuable Tongan fine mats are preserved and worn by the Tongan royal family.

(Wikipedia, *s.v.* [Taʻovala](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ta%CA%BBovala&oldid=848025078))

[image: A just married couple still in their wedding taʻovala]

*Decorated taʻovala worn at a Tongan marriage; photograph James Foster ([User:Tauʻolunga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Tau%CA%BBolunga)), 1989; available on Wikipedia; public domain.*

Comment: This answers my question precisely! Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Hats woven from palm fronds and other leaves are quite practical.

For example,

> A Panama hat (toquilla straw hat) is a traditional brimmed straw hat of Ecuadorian origin. Traditionally, hats were made from the plaited leaves of the [*Carludovica palmata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carludovica_palmata) plant, known locally as the toquilla palm or jipijapa palm, although it is a palm-like plant rather than a true palm. (Wikipedia, *s.v.* [Panama hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Panama_hat&oldid=882715867))
>
> The *jaapi* or *japi* is a traditional conical hat from Assam, India and Odisha, India which is made from tightly woven bamboo and/or cane and *tokou paat* ([*Trachycarpus martianus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trachycarpus_martianus)) a large, palm leaf. The word *jaapi* derives from *jaap* meaning a bundle of *taku* leaves. (Wikipedia, *s.v.* [Jaapi](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jaapi&oldid=887352448))
>
> The Thai farmer's hat or *ngob*, is a traditional hat used in Thailand. More complex in design than the related Asian conical hat, the *ngob* is made of [*ola* palm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corypha_umbraculifera) leaves laid over a plaited bamboo-strip frame. (Wikipedia, *s.v.* [Thai farmer's hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Thai_farmer%27s_hat&oldid=886281555))

Comment: This was downvoted?  We need a clarification from the OP: hats woven from palm fronds are *unprocessed.*  They really are a type of clothing that incorporates leaves.  Plant fiber, in my mind, means processing: such as converting Hemp to rope and then doing something with the rope (call it a really thick thread).  So, Enthusiastic, can you tell us if this answer (short and without citation though it may be.  Roger, a single-sentence answer is almost always flagged as low-quality) is basically within your expectations?

Comment: @JBH By me. "My question is if there's any actual historical precedent for this", This dawg dont hunt as per OP's question. I stand by my vote, the OP is free to change their question and invalidate answers, then get their question closed/edit rolled back for doing so.

Comment: @Agrajag, As a low-quality answer, a downvote was justified (and I appreciate your reponding), but what do you mean by "this dawg don't hunt?"  Palm frond hats have likely been woven since the dawn of history.  Do you not believe that?  Or are you merely pointing out that, without a citation, the answer is incomplete?

Comment: I've not seen evidence for it, not in life nor in the answer - citations would be good, pictures would be better. "Palm frond hats have likely been woven since the dawn of history" Most of world *recorded history* - literally the vast bulk of it, has occured in regions without palms. Also, does a hat count as clothing? (I ask the OP) @Enthusiastic Leviathan

Comment: I would add evidence like the jaapi palm hat: [The word jaapi derives from jaap meaning a bundle of taku \[,type of palm,\] leaves.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaapi) - they have been around since at least the 7th century. And the question says - whole leaves incorporated into clothing so it would count (and hats are counted as clothing at least according to every categorization program or analytic application I've ever worked on)

Comment: @Agrajag: *"Most of world recorded history - literally the vast bulk of it, has occured in regions without palms":* what? [Date palms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_palm) grow throughout Mesopotamia, the Near East (= Middle East in American), and Egypt. Actually, dates are a staple food in those parts of the world. History literally *began* in regions where date plams grow. For an example easy to remember, consider [Palm Sunday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_sunday).

Comment: Are hats really considered clothing?

Comment: I think a hat is a good example of leaves being incorporated directly into clothing, though I should've clarified that I was particularly curious about garments such as shirts, skirts, etc